# How to copy simple file with Maven?

Tags: maven, copy

I am learning Maven and I have some doubts on how to use `dependency:copy` plugin. After reading [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html) it is still not clear which `outputDirectory` should I use? And why there are two different ones?

Also I'll be happy to know how to define a simple file as an `artifactItem`?

```
<configuration>
    <artifactItems>
        <artifactItem>
            <!-- How to define here a simple file to copy it? -->
            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
            <outputDirectory>???</outputDirectory>
        </artifactItem>
    </artifactItems>
    <outputDirectory>???</outputDirectory>
    <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
    <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
</configuration>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For which purposes do you need to copy files?

Comment: I just need to copy some json file from some folder to public folder of my war archive.

Comment: Ok. Where have those files located? `src/main/resources/`? Otherwise i would recommend to put the into a location which is suggested by the [docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top level `outputDirectory` defines the output directory for all artifacts, it can be overriden for individual artifact items (see [outputDirectory parameter](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html#outputDirectory))

So usually, you do not define output directories for specific artifact items. If you define neither ouput directory, the default will apply, which is `${project.build.directory}/dependency`.

To your second question:

`dependency:copy` is for copying dependencies ***from* an artifact repository *to* your project**. You could upload your "file" to some artifact repository (Nexus, Artifactory), but I doubt that is what you want.